# LCD Display with I2C gives garbage when called by interrupt

Tags: python, i2c, interrupts, lcd

I have problems with a 2x16 LCD Display controlled via I2C. I use python 2.7 and have a Raspberry Pi Zero W. When called from the main loop everything works fine and I can access the display with

```
my_lcd.lcd_display_string("test", 1 , 0)
```

without problems. But when I call the same with a procedure called by interrupt I just get garbage on the LCD and everything is messed up.

The source code is like that

```
GPIO.setup(TasteHoch, GPIO.IN)  

def SWH( pin ):
   global my_lcd
   my_lcd.lcd_display_string("test", 1 , 0)  


my_lcd = I2C_LCD_driver.lcd()

GPIO.add_event_detect(TasteHoch, GPIO.FALLING, callback=SWH, bouncetime = 200)
```

The interrupt pin is wired (pull-up with capacitor bebouncing) to a breadboard push button, there are no other interrupts involved. As I checked the interrupt routine is only triggered once per push.

Comment: We need context.  How often are the interrupts generated?  Can they interrupt each other?  Please EDIT your question to include more detail of what is going on.

Comment: @joan: more details added

Comment: There is nothing obviously wrong the way you describe.  You probably need to add all the code and a photo of your connections to the question.

Comment: @joan: I finally found out, what was going on. The main loop was still executed when running the interrupt-code. So both calls on the I2C were interfering with each other. I have fixed it now by syncing the requests. Does anybody know if the execution of the remaining program can be paused when entering an interrupt routine?

Comment: I'm a bit surprised that gave a problem.  I'd have thought Linux would have made the I2C calls atomic.  Perhaps you need to set/clear a flag around the I2C calls and not call the I2C function if the flag is set.